# Using str_to_date and INSERT-SELECT with data in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I am inserting new data from a table, X, from Y. They are identical, except there is a column in X in which the date is formatted according to Str_to_date and an example of a date from Y is:
Mon May 11 03:17:40 UTC 2009. I am struggling with why I am getting an error in my code. My code is as follows:
`INSERT into X (str_to_date(REPLACE(date, 'UTC', ''), '%a %M %d %T %Y'))  SELECT date FROM Y`

When I use an online editor, it works when I replace date with "Mon May 11 03:17:40 UTC 2009" but I am confused as to why it doesn't work when taking from the other columns. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The call to `str_to_date()` needs to be in the `SELECT` list, not before it.

```
INSERT INTO X (date)
SELECT str_to_date(REPLACE(date, 'UTC', ''), '%a %M %d %T %Y')
FROM Y
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the convertion and replacing into the select statement

```
INSERT into X SELECT str_to_date(REPLACE(date, 'UTC', ''), '%a %M %d %T %Y') FROM Y
```